# Having issues getting my Tweepy stream to stop

Tags: python, socket.io, tweepy

Not able to get my stream to quit once I reach 100 tweets. I've tried many ways. Was hoping to keep the usage of "with open."

*Using a while loop while the file is open results in a messy undesirable JSON file
*Current usage of disconnect keeps streaming after reached 100 but data is broken

**Edited:**

1. Number of tweets and total tweets were recreated using self.
2. On every load of data, num_tweets was updated: self.num_tweets+=1. Then update pbar: self.pbar.update(1)
3. Outside of try statements, if self.num_tweets < self.total_tweets, then return True, else self.pbar.close() and return False

**Credit:** Chris Cookman

```html
def __init__(self, api=None):
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.total_tweets = int(input("Number of tweets:"))
        self.pbar = tqdm(total=self.total_tweets)
        self.unsaved = 0
        self.emojis = 0

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            portal_1 = creds()
            rawTweets = json.loads(data)
            self.num_tweets += 1
            self.pbar.update(1)
            ...
            ...
        except BaseException as e:
            print(colored("Error on_data: %s", "red") % str(e))
        if self.num_tweets < self.total_tweets:
            return True
        else:
            self.pbar.close()
            return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quit a stream with tweepy you need to return false from your on_status function, so if you change:

```
if self.num_tweets < 100:
    return True
    else:
        twitter_stream.disconnect()
```

To:

```
if self.num_tweets < 100:
    return True
else:
    self.pbar.close() # Closes the instance of the progress bar.
    return False # Closes the stream.
```

That should fix it. As one aside, for your progress bar by adding self.num_tweets each time you run:

```
self.pbar.update(self.num_tweets)
```

With update you are adding the number of tweets each time:

> Tweet 1  |  Tweet Count ='s 1  |  Progress bar ='s 1 (1)
>
> Tweet 2  |  Tweet Count ='s 2  |  Progress bar ='s 1 + 2 (3)
>
> Tweet 3  |  Tweet Count ='s 3  |  Progress bar ='s 3 + 3 (6)

From your code I assume your intent is to increment them instead, so to do this you just need to change it to:

```
self.pbar.update(1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked! :) Thank you man, I've been stuck in this hole for days!